# Integrate Windows Authentication spring security

Tags: spring-security, jboss, single-sign-on, spring-oauth2, spring-security-kerberos

- Tried waffle working successfully as needed in windows environment but my     application server is hosted on *nix environment.
- So waffle solutions doesn't meet my requirement.
- Tried kerberos solutions quite difficult to configure as compared to Waffle not able to meet my requirement.

My requirement - When user hit the URL of my web application he/she would get be authenticated by windows authentication or if possible can be able to get the **remote user** or clientname (windows account name) from request object.

Any suggestion would be helpful .

Comment: IMHO you'd need a LDAP/Active Directory [integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html)

Comment: @LaurIvan: LDAP authentication is already implemented,but currently what i nedded is to implement the windows authentication where able to login application without  entering username/password with current windows logged in username.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have an plain AD (without ADFS), then the only option is to use SPNEGO (spring-security-kerberos) to get 'auto-login' (SSO) to your app. The UserPrincipalName will be provided in the Kerberos token. When generating the keytab file (for your app/service) be sure to use '/crypto all' and take care about the KeyVersionNumber (as 'ktpass' updates/increments the key version within AD). However the clients must be able to obtain a service ticket for your app (i.e. Windows clients must be part of the domain). Also note that IE may fall back to presenting an NTLM token when the client is not able to obtain a Kerberos service ticket. AD and browser config/behavior are more challenging than the server side.

Comment: I am using ADFS  done configuration by referring this URL  http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.in/p/weblogic.html       Authentication is success but getting anonymous user from principal name.

Comment: Which `UserDetailsService` did you configure for the authentication provider?

Comment: import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

Comment: mind if i ask how to obtain that: "The UserPrincipalName will be provided in the Kerberos token."?

Comment: You may find the following thread interesting ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508555/decrypt-kerberos-ticket-using-spnego

Comment: thanks for response but my problem is not how to handle token but i dont know how to get it from user pc via http

Answer (score 0):

achieve what is needed by using reference link

1. http://kb.kaminskiengineering.com/node/89
2. [NTLM Authentication in a Web Application (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830957/ntlm-authentication-in-a-web-application-java)
   other who want to achieve more security can go kerberos-spengo also because spring security stop giving support to the above method which i used.